# Capturing a snapshot of a web page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I'm using [cloudinary's url2png](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/url2png_website_screenshots_addon) plugin to capture a rendered page on my site. It will capture the page but with none of the styling. The page takes a couple seconds to load so I'm thinking maybe it just needs to wait a little bit before capturing it?

Controller:

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])


    @user_items_designs = ItemsDesign.
        select('items_designs.id ,
                            items_designs.name,
                            items_designs.item_id,
                            items_designs.description,
                            items_designs.category,
                            items_designs.style,
                            items_designs.brand,
                            items_designs.color,
                            items_designs.make,
                            items_designs.special_name,
                            items_designs.likes,
                            items_designs.image_name,
                            items_designs.image_name_hover,
                            items_designs.image_name_selection,

                            users_items_designs.hide,
                            users_items_designs.location_id,

                            locations.z,
                            locations.x,
                            locations.y,
                            locations.height,
                            locations.width,
                            locations.section_id,

                            items.name as items_name,
                            items.name_singular as items_name_singular,

                            items.clickable,
                            sections.name as section_name'
    ).
        joins(:users_items_designs).
        where('user_id = ?', @user.id).
        joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN locations  ON locations.id = users_items_designs.location_id').
        joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN items  ON items.id = items_designs.item_id').
        joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN sections ON sections.id = locations.section_id')

    @items = []
    @user_items_designs.each do |item|
      location = Location.find(item.item_id)
      @items << {id: item.id, item_id: item.item_id, name: item.name, description: item.description, image_name: item.image_name, x: location.x.to_i, y: location.y.to_i, z: location.z.to_i}
    end
```

The code to capture the page has to be in the view:

```
<%
   snapshot = cl_image_tag("http:****",
                           :type => "url2png",
                           :sign_url => true)

%>
<%= snapshot %>
```

This builds the page to be captured:

```
<% @items.each do |image| %>
            <% puts image.inspect %>
            <div class="room_design_container_<%= image[:item_id] %>" style="position: absolute; left: <%= "#{image[:x]}px" %>; top: <%= "#{image[:y]}px" %>; z-index: <%= image[:z] %>;">
              <img class="room_design"
                   src="<%= image[:image_name].url %>"

                   data-main-src-client="<%= image[:image_name].url %>"
                   data-main-src-server="<%= image[:image_name].url %>"

                   data-design-id-server="<%= image[:id] %>"

                   data-design-item-id="<%= image[:item_id] %>"

                   data-design-location-id="<%= image[:location_id] %>"
              />
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify any [URL2PNG parameters](https://www.url2png.com/docs/) as a suffix of the original website being captured. The suffix should be `/url2png/` followed by any parameters of URL2PNG in the format of `key=value|key=value|key=value`.

Here's an example of setting the `delay` parameter:

```
cl_image_tag("http://www.example.com/url2png/delay=5|fullpage=false", 
             :type => "url2png", :sign_url => true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify any [URL2PNG parameters](https://www.url2png.com/docs/) as a suffix of the original website being captured. The suffix should be `/url2png/` followed by any parameters of URL2PNG in the format of `key=value|key=value|key=value`.

Here's an example of setting the `delay` parameter:

```
cl_image_tag("http://www.****.com/url2png/delay=5|fullpage=false", 
             :type => "url2png", :sign_url => true)
```